# Computing $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}n} $ with a power series- What did I do wrong?

Tags: calculus

The requested sum: $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}n}=
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^nn}$

My helper- this power series: $
\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{4^n}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{4}{x}}
$

Integration due to uniform convergence: $ \int \sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{4^n}=\int \frac{1}{1-\frac{4}{x}}$

This is what I get:$\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{4^{n+1}(n+1)}=-4\ln(4-x)$

Or: $
\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{4^{n}n}=-4\ln(4-x)
$

Finally what we need is: $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{4^{n}n}=-2\ln(4-x)$

Now I want to plug-in $x=1$ and get the requested result, but what bothers me is that this is a positive series and I get a negative number in the RHS, obivously something's wrong.

Please tell me what's wrong with the steps described above.

Thanks! :)

Comment: For starters, $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^n/4^n = \frac{1}{1-(x/4)}$, not $\frac{1}{1-(4/x)}$.

Comment: Well, first, the sum on the right hand side of the first line should start at $n=1$, not $n=0$.

Comment: @MartinWanvik: This is a type mistake also. the integral is correct.

Comment: @DavidMitra: sorry, this is a type mistake. Still I don't understand how come it is negative.

Comment: When integrating, you need definite integrals$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^x (t/4)^n \,dt = \int_0^x {(t/4)\over 1-(t/4) }\, dt$$

Comment: @DavidMitra: Ok, thanks, but does it have something to do with the negative result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your method is that you're using primitives and not definite integrals:

$$\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n + 1}}{{\left( {\frac{x}{4}} \right)}^{n + 1}}}  =  - \log \left( {1 - \frac{x}{4}} \right) =  - \log \left( {4 - x} \right) + \log 4 = \int\limits_0^x {\frac{1}{{4 - t}}dt} $$

---

Since you know

$$-\log \left( {1 - x} \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{x^n}}}{n}} $$

You simply plug in $1/4$. You get

$$\eqalign{
  &  - \frac{1}{2}\log \left( {1 - \frac{1}{4}} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n{4^n}}}}   \cr 
  & \frac{1}{2}\log \left( {\frac{4}{3}} \right) =  \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n{4^n}}}}  \cr} $$

---

You should be thinking about differentiating, not integrating. You have

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {n{{\left( {\frac{1}{4}} \right)}^n}} $$

So you might want to find

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {n{x^n}}  = f\left( x \right)$$

Adn the plug in $1/4$. Use

$$\eqalign{
  & F\left( x \right) = \frac{1}{{1 - x}} = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{x^n}}   \cr 
  & x\frac{d}{{dx}}F\left( x \right) = x\frac{d}{{dx}}\frac{1}{{1 - x}} = x\frac{d}{{dx}}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{x^n}}   \cr 
  & xF'\left( x \right) = \frac{x}{{{{\left( {1 - x} \right)}^2}}} = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {n{x^n}}   \cr 
  & \frac{1}{2}xF'\left( x \right) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{x}{{{{\left( {1 - x} \right)}^2}}} = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {n{x^n}}  \cr} $$

Now plug in $1/4$ to get

$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{{\frac{1}{4}}}{{{{\left( {1 - \frac{1}{4}} \right)}^2}}} = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {n{{\left( {\frac{1}{4}} \right)}^n}} $$

$$\frac{2}{9} = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {n{{\left( {\frac{1}{4}} \right)}^n}} $$

Comment: Thanks Peter, but this is not the requested sum :)

Comment: @Jozef (!) Sorry, I misread the $n$! Will ad the right answer shortly.

Comment: @Jozef Ok, what about now?

Comment: but it suppose to work in all the radius of convergence which is $(-4,4)$, so what's wrong with $1$, how come it is negative? something's wrong with my way?

Comment: You're using primitves instead of definite integrals. You have a constant $C$ you're not considering.

Comment: Oh, It's critical! Thanks a lot peter for all the explanations!!

Comment: @Jozef Anytime, Jozef.

Answer (score 3):

It would be best to proceed as Peter does starting with the series representation of $\ln(1-x)$.

However, to address your argument:

You wish to compute
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over 2^{2n+1} n}=
{1\over2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty { 1\over n \, 4^n }
$$
(this was your first error, the sum starts at $n=1$).

Using the Geometric series:
$$\tag{1}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (x/4)^n= {x/4\over 1-(x/4)}= {1\over 1-(x/4)}-1 
$$
(your sum of the series was your second error).

If $|x|<4$:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^x (t/4)^n\,dt=  \int_0^x {1\over 1-(t/4)}-1\, dt 
$$
(note, you need to take *definite* integrals).

Whence
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty{x^{n+1}\over 4^n (n+1)}=  -4\ln|1-(x/4)|-x
$$

Substituting $x=1$ gives:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over 4^n (n+1)}=  -4\ln(3/4)-1\approx0.15073
$$

So
$$\eqalign{
{1\over2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty { 1\over n \, 4^n }
&={1\over2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty { 1\over( n +1)\, 4^{n+1} }\cr
&={1\over8} \sum_{n=0}^\infty { 1\over( n +1)\, 4^{n } }\cr
&={1\over8} [{1}   -4\ln(3/4)-1]\cr
&={1\over8} [   -4\ln(3/4) ]\cr
&=  {  \ln(4/3)\over 2 }\cr
}
$$

Comment: David, Thanks a lot!